# MarkItUp! continuous preview refresh without hitting enter

Tags: markdown, markitup

I'm using MarkItUp (http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/) and can't really figure out how to get it to continuously update the preview pane as each character is typed (or even when a 'space' is encountered). By default it refreshes the preview pane only when the enter key is hit.

Is there any way to customize this behavior? The documentation mentions a `previewAutoRefresh` key, but setting it results in the update-on-enter thing, not any faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same technique as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380603/displaying-preview-panel-automatically-in-markitup-editor/2840724#2840724).

```
$(".mymarkitupclass").keyup(function(){
    $('a[title="Preview"]').trigger('mousedown');
});
```

Note that this will send a new request to your webserver on every keypress, so if you have a lot of users, this'll be a lot of hits.

Answer (score 2):

Very late but a better solution is to start a timer (1 sec) for each keypress so that the preview is done only once, when the user do a pause (this code snippet used JQuery timer plugin):

```
    $('#markitup').keydown(function() {
    $(this).stopTime();
    $(this).oneTime(1000, function() { $('a[title="Preview"]').trigger('mouseup'); });
});
```

For more detail you can see the excellent post on coding the wheel [Syntax highlighting](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/syntax-highlighting-stackoverflow-google-prettify) talking about textarea preview.

Comment: This throws: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopTime' (and I have jQuery timer plugin -> https://raw.github.com/jbrooksuk/jQuery-Timer-Plugin/master/jquery.timer.js

Comment: I'm using an old jquery timer plug-in, I've copied the script here  http://pastebin.com/g2dY6hzs

Answer (score -2):

previewAutoRefresh is on by default.

The preview is refreshed at any markup insertion (or Enter key pressed).
The content of the preview is sent by ajax to a server side parser to render the markup language (textile, markdown, bbcode etc). Doing this operation on every key stroke is almost impossible (slow and heavy).

The markItUp! built-in preview is just a helper. You can disable it and code your own preview, using a client side script (Showdown for example) as you would have to do with a regular textarea.

:)

Comment: you described what MarkItUp is. It's on the website. How does this help?