# Displaying preview panel automatically in markitup! editor

Tags: jquery, markup, markitup

I'm using the [markitup!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) as a markdown editor ([example](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/markdown/)).

Currently, I need to press the preview button (green tick) to display the preview panel.

I would like the preview to be displayed automatically - how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no experience with this editor but

```
$('a[title="Preview"]').trigger('mouseup');
```

called after the editor loads seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anybody else is following the accepted answer and runs into problems:

```
$('a[title="Preview"]').trigger('mousedown');
```

worked for me (while 'mouseup' didn't). Maybe they changed the behaviour in the newest version of *markItUp!* (v1.1.7)?

Comment: +1 worked for me, however this only does it when I add a 'new like' would love to see the update on every key entry. Gonna have to research how that's done.

Comment: Interestingly `trigger('mousedown')` did not work for me, but `trigger('mouseup')` did. The markitup file has the version `v 1.1.x` in it

Comment: As for 1.1.15 works again `mouseup`, not `mousedown`.

Answer (score 3):

[Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380603/displaying-preview-panel-automatically-in-markitup-editor/1380922#1380922) worked. For the sake of completeness, here's where I added his code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('#markdown').markItUp(myMarkdownSettings);
    $('a[title="Preview"]').trigger('mouseup');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note that this answer is nearly 4 years old. Try [Volker's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2840724/113962) above. If that doesn't work, try asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do it by hacking it a little : 
in the source file add

autoShowPreview :       false,

as a field in the options object 
so it will look like :

```
options = { id:                     '',
                nameSpace:              '',
                root:                   '',
                previewHandler:         false,
                previewInWindow:        '', // 'width=800, height=600, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes'
                previewInElement:       '',
                previewAutoRefresh:     true,
                autoShowPreview :       true,  //custom option here : 
                previewPosition:        'after',
                previewTemplatePath:    '~/templates/preview.html',
                previewParser:          false,
                previewParserPath:      '',
                previewParserVar:       'data',
                resizeHandle:           true,
                beforeInsert:           '',
                afterInsert:            '',
                onEnter:                {},
                onShiftEnter:           {},
                onCtrlEnter:            {},
                onTab:                  {},
                markupSet:          [   { /* set */ } ]
            };
```

Then near the end of the document around line 610 there is the call to the init(); function.
You can change it like this :

```
init();
if(options.autoShowPreview){
     preview();
     refreshPreview();
}
```

You can always disable it if not needed by modifying our custom prop at initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1457-How-To-Build-A-Custom-jQuery-Selector.htm) shows how to select by title ('preview') in this case. You can then select the anchor tag ('a') with title preview and then click it.

Best of luck,

Dan